# How to highlight multiple rows in Ag-Grid Vue

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid-vue

I have an issue with highlight multiple rows in ag-grid vue,
I want to get hover a row and doing highlight to three rows at the same time.
For instance:

[image]

As you can see, there is one row in highlight, I want to highlight three of them.

It is possible?

Comment: what did you tried so far ?

Comment: I tried to change some CSS objects but it's not really make it happen...

Comment: Can you please share the example code in codepen or jsfiddle. So that i can look into that.

Comment: [link](https://codepen.io/dyeistun-the-looper/pen/XWEQMLb) This is an example of ag-grid from google, if you succeed to highlight three rows at the same hover line, it will be nice